# SQL condition where 2 values share common character

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, where-clause

I'm trying to create a query that lists staffID, staffName and staffDOB, but only of staff that first and last names begin with the same letter. So I have both staffFirst and staffLast as individual columns, will join them together. I will not be customising staffID and staffDOB. I would like it to return the name of staff like adam apple = a apple, so the output would look like:

```
staffID | staffName | staffDOB
------------------------------
1       | A Apple   | 12/10/99
....    | ....      | ....
```

All columns are in the same table "N_Staff". I am using HeidiSQL which I believe uses MySQL. I know how to grab the data of each column, though it is selecting the first letters of both first and last names and comparing them which is confusing me as it is not an specific letter I am looking for but any letter that is common on both tables of index [0].

Thus far:

```
SELECT staffID FROM N_Staff,
SELECT staffFirst, staffLast AS staffName
FROM N_Staff WHERE ... , --perhaps should be using LEFT ?
SELECT staffDOB from N_Staff;
```

Comment: Okay and how do I select first character of each string?

Comment: To select first character of each string, you can use SUBSTRING ( MyColumn, 1 , 1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT staffID, CONCAT(LEFT(staffFirst,1), ' ', staffLast) AS staffName, staffDOB
FROM N_Staff
WHERE LEFT(staffFirst,1) = LEFT(staffLast,1)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the LEFT statement?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
    SELECT * FROM NS_WORDS; 
    mani
    nikhil
    sugandh
    mining
    _lkdnsad
    _lkdndsadnjas
    _lk
    _ja
    _ls
    _lsa
    nikhil nikhil
    nikhil name

SELECT * FROM NS_WORDS
where not( to_char(SUBSTR(a,1,1))=to_char(substr(a,instr(a,' ',1,1),1))); 

output:
nikhil nikhil
nikhil name
```

your where will go like:

```
where not( to_char(SUBSTR(staffName ,1,1))=to_char(substr(staffName 
,instr(staffName ,' ',1,1),1)));
```